# C++ Dangling pointer issue

Tags: c++, dangling-pointer, raylib

I am using the Raylib GUI framework for a project that displays all the nodes within an iteration of the Collatz Conjecture. In my program, I have a class for a `Node` object that acts simply as a circle with a labelled number. The variable `text` in my `draw` method, however, has an issue; `C26815: The pointer is dangling because it points at a temporary instance which was destroyed`. I'm new to C++ and don't have access to any books to teach me at the moment, hence I'm not entirely sure what a "dangling" pointer is or what it means, but I'm fairly certain it's the reason I can't display any text on my nodes. Here's my `Node` class:

```cpp
class Node {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
    int radius;
public:
    Vector2 get_pos() {
        return Vector2{ (float)x, (float)-value * 25 };
    }

    void set_radius(int newRadius) {
        radius = newRadius;
    }
    
    void set_value(int newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    }

    void set_x(int newX) {
        x = newX;
    }

    void set_y(int newY) {
        y = newY;
    }

    void draw() {
        
        if (value) {
            const char* text = std::to_string(value).c_str();
            Vector2 size = MeasureTextEx(GetFontDefault(), text, 32.0f, 0.0f);
            Vector2 pos = get_pos();
            DrawCircle(pos.x, pos.y, radius, WHITE);
            DrawText(text, pos.x - size.x / 2, pos.y - size.y / 2, 32, BLACK);
        }
    }
};
```

Any help or explanation as to what's going on would be appreciated.

EDIT: Other people have had similar issues on other questions but none of the answers made sense to me or felt applicable to my situation.

Comment: _I'm new to C++ and don't have access to any books to teach me at the moment_ Once you have some pennies in the piggy bank, you might consult [this list of curated books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  You'll find it hard going without something decent to learn from.

Comment: @PaulSanders yeah I've looked at this exact list before that was linked in another question I had, I'm going for A Tour of C++ first and I then might pick up another one if it doesn't suit me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
const char* text = std::to_string(value).c_str();
```

You are calling `c_str()` which returns a pointer to the buffer of the temporary returned by `std::to_string(value)`. This temporaries lifetime ends at the end of this line. The pointer returned from `c_str` is only valid as long as the string is still alive.

If `DrawText` copies the string (rather than just copying the pointer you pass) you can fix it via

```
        std::string text = std::to_string(value);
        Vector2 size = MeasureTextEx(GetFontDefault(), text, 32.0f, 0.0f);
        Vector2 pos = get_pos();
        DrawCircle(pos.x, pos.y, radius, WHITE);
        DrawText(text.c_str(), pos.x - size.x / 2, pos.y - size.y / 2, 32, BLACK);
```